# How find this $\frac{3x^3+125y^3}{x-y}$ minimum value

Tags: inequality

> let $x>y>0$,and such $xy=1$, find follow minimum of the value
>   $$\dfrac{3x^3+125y^3}{x-y}$$

My idea: let $x=y+t,t>0$
then
$$\dfrac{3x^3+125y^3}{x-y}=\dfrac{3(y+t)^3+125y^3}{t}=3t^2+3yt+3y^2+\dfrac{128y^3}{t}$$
and $$(y+t)y=1$$

I think this can use AM-GM inequality.But I can't.

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you use basic calculus (first derivative, extreme points, etc.)?

Comment: This is  Junior student problem,So they don't know the derivative
,But Thank you

Comment: Ok @nan...and I really want to see a solution without calculus as I've no idea what to do here without it with the given info.

Comment: Oh,@DonAntonio,Thank you.

Comment: How it is possible to have $x>y>0$ s.t. $xy=1$? Did you mean something like "find the minimum of the given function on $xy=1$ with $x,y>0?$" I am bit confused, sorry.

Comment: @Avitus, What's the problem? For example $\;x=2\;,\;\;y=\frac12\;$ ...Yet I agree it seems more logical to require *only* $\;x,y>0\;$ without the $\;x>y\;$ bit.

Comment: @DonAntonio I struggle with the double (strict )inequalities $x>y>0$ combined with the hyperbola :-) Probably it is $x>0$, $y>0$ on the hyperbola.

Comment: I can't see why you struggle, @Avitus: my last comment gave you an example of $\;x>y>0\;,\;\;xy=1\;$ ...

Comment: I am fine with your comment @DonAntonio but only *now* I see the $t>0$ condition in the OP. Ok, no doubt anymore, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

First note that $x>1$ and simplify like this:
$$\frac{3x^3+125y^3}{x-y}=\frac{3x^6+125x^3y^3}{x^4-x^3y}=\frac{3x^6+125}{x^4-x^2}$$
Set $t=x^2$. Now we want to find $a\ge0$ such that
$$\frac{3t^3+125}{t^2-t}\ge a\Longleftrightarrow3t^3+at+125\ge at^2$$
for $t>1$ where the equality is possible.

Note that we could use AM-GM inequality on $t^3+t^3+t^3+at+5^3$, but that equality is possible only if all terms are equal, i.e. $t^3=at=5^3\Longrightarrow t=5, a=5^2$.

Luckily this gives us exactly what we wanted:
$$t^3+t^3+t^3+5^2t+5^3\ge5\sqrt[5]{t^{10}5^5}=5^2t^2$$
Therefore $a=25$ is the minimum and it's possible only for $t=5\Longleftrightarrow x=\sqrt5, y=\dfrac1{\sqrt5}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{3x^3+125y^3}{x-y}=\dfrac{3x^6+125x^3y^3}{x^4-x^3y}=\dfrac{3x^6+125}{x^2(x^2-1)}=\dfrac{3(p+1)^3+125}{p(p+1)},p=x^2-1>0$

$\dfrac{3(p+1)^3+125}{p(p+1)}=3p+6+\dfrac{3}{p}+\dfrac{125}{p(p+1)}$

$3p$ is mono increasing function, $\dfrac{3}{p}+\dfrac{125}{p(p+1)}$ is mono decreasing function,so there must be only a min point.with try $p=1,2,3,4,5,6$,we can guess $p=4$ is the point. now we need $\dfrac{1}{p}=\dfrac{k}{p(p+1)}$when we taking AM-GM, so $k=5 $ if $p=4$ is right one, the last step is to verify:

$3p+6+\dfrac{3}{p}+\dfrac{125}{p(p+1)}=25\times\dfrac{(p+1)}{20}+28\times\dfrac{p}{16}+3\times\dfrac{1}{p}+25\times\dfrac{5}{p(p+1)}+\dfrac{9}{4} \ge 91\left(\left(\dfrac{p+1}{20}\right)^{25}\left(\dfrac{p}{16}\right)^{28}\left(\dfrac{1}{p}\right)^3\left(\dfrac{5}{p(p+1)}\right)^{25}\right)^{\frac{1}{91}}+\dfrac{9}{4}=\dfrac{91}{4}+\dfrac{9}{4}=25$

when $\dfrac{(p+1)}{20}=\dfrac{p}{16}=\dfrac{1}{p}=\dfrac{5}{p(p+1)}$ get "=" ie. $p=4$

so min is $25$ when $x=\sqrt{p+1}=\sqrt{5}$

Answer (score -1):

continuation:
let $x-y=t$, $xy=1$, we get:
$$x=\frac{1}{2}t+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{t^2+4},\\y=-\frac{1}{2}t+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{t^2+4}$$
then we have
$$f=\frac{3x^3+125y^3}{x-y}\\=\frac{-61t^3+64t^2\sqrt{t^2+4}-183t+64\sqrt{t^2+4}}{t}$$
we calculate the differential:
$$g=\frac{df}{dt}=-\frac{2(61t^3\sqrt{t^2+4}-64t^4-128t^2+128)}{t^2\sqrt{t^2+4}}$$
let $g=0$, we get the good solution:
$$t=\frac{4}{5}\sqrt{5}$$
let $t=\frac{4}{5}\sqrt{5}$, we have
$$f(\frac{4}{5}\sqrt{5})=25$$

Comment: As noted in the comments, the OP has not yet studied calculus at all. This was the first question asked to him in this thread.